# Horizontal scroll - syntaxhighlighter

Tags: wordpress, syntaxhighlighter

I was googling to find a solution for this forever, I was so close but still can't find the problem...

The closest solution I found was at this site But:

I want exactly the opposite of what this guy posted: [Automatic line break in js SyntaxHighlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286733/automatic-line-break-in-js-syntaxhighlighter)

He wants instead of horizontal bar to break the code down, but what do I want is instead of breaking the code down, to display a horizontal bar.

I've used SH on multiple projects and never actually had this issue till now.

I've installed it in wordpress as a plugin in a custom theme, I modified the theme css file(s) and the syntax highlighter's file(s) (.css), but still nothing's going on.

Here's a screenshot [image]

If you have any suggestion what the problem might be, please tell me - any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is so very little on SyntaxHighlighter that comes up in Google searches, either referencing WordPress or with the standard version for non-WordPress sites.  So, please go ahead write up a good answer for anyone in the future who may encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a combination of overflow and white-space css properties.

```
pre {overflow:scroll;}
.pre-wrap {white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

Please see the footle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YwxSc/6/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, that didn't help But it gave me an idea of where the problem might be.

After wasting day and a half, I finally found the problem, and it was in the main theme .css file.

All I had to do was change
code { white-space: normal; } to code { white-space: nowrap; }

This was really ridiculous, but thanks for helping out :)